# Ntext fields have False value when obtained through PHP odbc

Tags: php, t-sql, odbc

I'm prompting the results of a query on MS Server in an HTML table using odbc_result() on the ressources obtained through an odbc_exec().

My problem is that ntext fields have False as value.

To get around this issue, I can do a `RTRIM(CAST(ntext_field AS VARCHAR(8000)))`. Put all the ntext fields at the end of the view can works too but it disorganizes the display.
This works when I design the queries and when I know which fields I'm using but it doesn't works anymore on a `SELECT * FROM RandomTable`query.

So my question is : "how can I get the correct value of the ntext fields regardless of whether it exists or not, its position or the number of fields of this type ?"

Both T-SQL side and PHP-ODBC side solutions are accepted of course.

I thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: `ntext_field ` is deprecated. Change it to `nvarchar(max)` and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly found a solution instead of send to my odbc_exec() function a query like `SELECT *
 FROM MyTable`, I made this function :

```
$SQLCodePrep = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'";

$result=odbc_exec($conn, $SQLCodePrep);
$ColumnList = QueryPrompter::InsertIntoArray($result);
              # This function take as argument the result of a query and put each row in an array, and each of these arrays in a bigger array (wich represent the table)


$SQLCode = "SELECT "; 

for ($i=0; $i<count($ColumnList); $i++)
{
    if (in_array($ColumnList[$i][1], $DefaultArray = array('ntext', 'text', 'image')) OR (in_array($ColumnList[$i][1], $DefaultArray = array('nvarchar', 'varchar')) AND $ColumnList[$i][2] == '-1'))
    {
        $Column = "RTRIM(CAST(".$ColumnList[$i][0]." AS VARCHAR(8000))) AS '".$ColumnList[$i][0]."'";
    }
    else
    {
        $Column = $ColumnList[$i][0];           
    }


    if($i < count($ColumnList)-1)
    {
        $Column .= ", ";
    }

    $SQLCode .= $Column;
}


$SQLCode .= " FROM MyTable";
```

Then we can do a `$result=odbc_exec($conn, $SQLCode);` as we use to do and everything works as I wanted